# TTR:StockSymbols() - Receiving stock symbols error

Tags: r, ttr

This issue has happened multiple times now and I don't know how to fix it. Has anyone dealt with this error in the `TTR` package?

```
library('TTR')

symbols <- TTR::stockSymbols()
Fetching AMEX symbols...
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The operation timed out'
```

Comment: See [issue #98](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/TTR/issues/98). I can download the file manually, but not programmatically. read.csv(url, ...), curl_download, or other options will return an error. Looks like the issue is not so much TTR but the nasdaq server.

Comment: Great thank you, did it manually as well as a backup!